# set cookie add 1 to cookie name everytime user clicks button

Tags: php, html, cookies

So I'm currently making a site that includes purchases. Instead of signing up I want to set a cookie then every time a user clicks the buy button, it'll add 1 to the cookie name. Then when the cookie name = $_POST['user'] + 10 I want to echo 'too many right now' or something along those lines. I can't get this to work and have tried multiple times. There is no error in my html or anywhere else in my html. I just can't get this to work. Here is my code:

```
<?php  
$cookie_name = $_POST['user'];
setcookie($cookie_name,  time() + (86400 * 30), "/");

if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
print 'Cookie with name "' . $cookie_name . '" does not exist...';
} else {
print'Cookie with name "'. $cookie_name .'"value is:'.$_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}
if(isset($_POST['button'])) {
setcookie($cookie_name, '+1', $cookie_value);

}

if (setcookie($cookie_name == $_POST['user'], +10)) {
echo 'to many right now';
}
?>
```

I obviously have a html form with the attributes name = 'button' and name = 'user' I just want to know how I can achieve what I said I was trying to do above. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Does the button click refresh the page load? BTW, Cookies are read from the header data, not after the page is processed. From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php): Cookies are part of the HTTP header, so setcookie() must be called before any output is sent to the browser

Comment: I think you need to read more carefully what `setcookie` does in the manual: http://php.net/setcookie You've used it three times here, and each time expect it to work differently, including somehow doing maths for you, and never actually use it correctly to set the value you actually want in the cookie.

Comment: @IMSoP this is my first time using cookies. Is there any other way to achieve what I asked?

Comment: It is not your use of cookies that is wrong, it is your basic understanding of how PHP works, but hopefully my answer below will set you on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You are clearly out of your depth, and are hoping that somehow, `setcookie` will do all the work for you, reading, adjusting, and testing the cookie. As [the manual makes clear](http://php.net/setcookie) it does only one thing:

> setcookie() defines a cookie to be sent along with the rest of the HTTP headers.

It takes two main parameters: a string which is the name of the cookie to send to the browser, and a string which is the value to send; the other arguments are all optional, and change when and where it will be visible; just ignore them for now. Note that the second argument is not an equation, or an adjustment to be made, it's just a string of text to store.

As ever, the key is to *break your problem down*; go through each of these steps, and make sure it's working before you go to the next step:

1. Decide on your cookie's name (the part that won't change, because it's how you'll find it again later).
2. Test if the cookie has already been set on a previous request.
3. If it has, put its value into a new variable.
4. Increment that value by 1
5. If there is no existing cookie, set the variable to an initial value, like 0 or 1
6. Send a cookie to the browser with the new value, using `setcookie`
7. Test if the value has reached some threshold, and echo a message.

Note that in the above, there is only one call to `setcookie`; most of your logic is just working with numbers, and doesn't need to know about cookies at all.